# Kotlin multiplatform check execution platform within common code

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a common module that is consumed by JVM, JS, and Native projects. Within the common module, I would like to do something like the following:

```kotlin
fun currentPlatform(): String {
  // return "JVM", "JS", or "Native" depending on where this code is executing.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the common module, I have

```kotlin
enum class KotlinPlatform {
 JVM,JS,Native
}
expect val currentPlatform: KotlinPlatform
```

In the JVM module, I have:

```kotlin
actual val currentPlatform = KotlinPlatform.JVM
```

And the above can be repeated for JS and any other modules as well.